# Paypal IPN verification fails due to host name does not match certificate in sandbox environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I've been using IPN verification successfully for years now. It suddenly stopped working.
I send the verification request to https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate

It seems like there is something wrong with their certificate not matching 'ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com'
This is the url listed in their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/IPNImplementation/).

I also tried using [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672421/paypal-ipn-http-error-400-php-using-paypal-git-code)
but still did not work.

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: What is the precise error? Both URLs, https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com and https://www.sandbox.paypal.com , with or without `/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate` should load fine in a browser. Assuming they do, the problem is your environment not able to do what your browser can.

Comment: I ran into the same error with an old script, which uses www.paypal.com domain. It looks like some kind of internal server error in PayPal.